# Creating Java Exe

Tags: java, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my java program to an .exe file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Hi,

How can i create an executable (EXE) from my Java program?

Thanks for your Help

Comment: As Johan pointed out this is probably a duplicate. Be sure to either do a search or check the list of similar posts that is displayed after typing in the title of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) is another good option.

Comment: JWS is x-plat & auto-updating, what does JSmooth offer that is not supported by the API provided by Oracle?

Comment: Glad you are happy with it, doesn't mean people cannot have other options.

Comment: @AndrewThompson a program that can be used while fully offline?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  I take it that by 'while fully offline' you mean machines that don't have an internet connection at all?  Shrugs (sure) OK.  For that last .1% of machines where it is only practical to deliver software on CD, USB stick etc. agreed.  But then the flip-side is, is it really worth supporting that .1% of the market?  (Of course, the statistics were made up on the spot, to suit my point.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson You asked for what JSmooth offered that is not supported by the API provided by Oracle.  I mentioned one thing that JSmooth provides for that Java WebStart doesn't. Just because that thing is not important to you, it may be important to others.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Fair enough.

Comment: @AndrewThompson glad to enlighten you.  Feel free to provide details on how to distribute Java WebStart programs on e.g. USB-media.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  *"Feel free to provide details on how to distribute Java WebStart programs"*  While 'offline install' works, I never found it to be practical for anything more than development.  So no, I am neither claiming that a JWS app. can be provided off USB/CD, nor offering to show how.  BTW - Why the ..sudden interest in this answer/comments that are more than a year old?  I'm starting to wonder if the 'USB stick' with my comments on it, only just arrived in the postal mail this morning.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson No need for wondering. I simply used the search box to locate answers on how to create EXE-wrapped jar files, and then traverse them all to get an 10km impression on how the SO community think this is solved best.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using launch4j to create and executable wrapper:
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/

Comment: JWS is x-plat & auto-updating, what does Launch4J offer that is not supported by the API provided by Oracle?