# Need a free tools to create exe file from java

Tags: java, exe

I tried to generate a exe file form my java source. I followed the following link.

**[http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eteks.com%2Ftips%2FtipCreationExe.html.](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.eteks.com/tips/tipCreationExe.html)**

But the exe file couldn't produced. I have the following exception.

Unable to execute file: c:/Program Files/Bienvenue/Bienvenue.exe                  CreateProcess failed; code 2. The system cannot find the file specified

Any suggestion pls..

Comment: You could go for an executable jar also.

Comment: Thanks, but I want an exe file, not an executable jar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Comment: -1 Please search in SO before you post a question that already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Launch4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/) will be a good solution. you can embed the JVM in to the application.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to either do a search or check the list of similar posts that is displayed after typing in the title of your post.

[How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

[Compiling a java program into an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe)

[How do I create an .exe for a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516399/how-do-i-create-an-exe-for-a-java-program)

[Creating Java Exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250997/creating-java-exe)

Answer (score 0):

jsmooth is a nice tool to convert jar to exe

please take a look at this link
http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/